# Set default image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement where i need to set a default image if the image is not uploaded by user.
I am trying to set the image using javascript. My image is located in images folder of my project in eclipse.

my html code is:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Upload Image :</td>
    <td>
         <input type="file"  id="imageNonSaml" name="imageNonSaml" value=""/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

my javascript is :

```
function testSSO(){
    var image=document.getElementById("imageNonSaml").value;
    if(image==null || image==''){
        alert("inside if");
        document.getElementById('imageNonSaml').setAttribute('name',"/assets/img/generic.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: @til_b  No console errors. i am facing problem in setting the image path.

Comment: are you trying to set input's value?

Comment: You try to set the value of the file upload field. What you probably want is a <img src="..."> tag that displays the image. I suggest you read a basic book on HTML and how it works; sorry for the rudeness but you seem to lack some basic understanding of HTML. We were all beginners once, but this site will not teach you programming.

Comment: @vladkras  No, the image was already there in images folder of my project. I am trying to set that image.

Comment: Hi. I think I understand what you are trying to do here. You want to set a default image if none is provided. You don't need to use javascript for that. Do this server side, where you process the form.

Comment: @sahu What server side language are you using?

Comment: @jeevanjose i am using spring mvc in java

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to change the `name` attribute of the file input. It's not possible to set the path of the a file input. The reason for this is security - if it was possible, a malicuous site could set the value and automatically submit the form in order to steal files from the user's system.

If you're intending to set the `src` of an `<img />` then you need to reference it in your `getElementById()` call, and set the `src` property, not the `name` attribute.

```
document.getElementById('myimg').src = "/assets/img/generic.png";
```

Comment: Did you create an `<img id="myimg" />`?

Comment: i kept `<img id="myimg" />` but the value i am getting is `undefined`

Comment: When do you run the code? Make sure you run it after the element is in the DOM and ready (e.g. `window.onload`), if you run it straight away the image might not be there when you try to access it

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the FILE typed input with JavaScript. This would be a major security issue, if sites could automatically upload files from your machine.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
function testSSO(){
 var image = document.getElementById("imageNonSaml");
 if(image.value == null || image.value == ''){
  alert("inside if");
  image.value = "/assets/img/generic.png";
 }
}
```

Comment: you should do this with your server script or set a default in MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set a default image, but not with the File element using JavaScript. Basically you have 3 options:

1.) Set it as a default value in your database. Thus if no change is made, a default image is loaded when requested from the database.

2.) Set the image in your server side language. Thus if no image is in the database, a default image is shown. `<img src="<% echo image %>" />`

3.) Set the Img element src attribute in JavaScript to the default image if no image can be loaded.

With jQuery this would look similar to below:

```
$("#imageid").attr("src","mydomain.com/img/imgname.png");
```

Or without jQuery see jay harris answer.

As to the best option, it depends on your requirements. Number 3 could be problematic if someone had JavaScript disabled (not likely nowadays) but still could happen. I would consider 1 or 2 based upon the exact requirements of my project.

**EDIT:**

To set your path in JavaScript I would use the full domain like so:

```
//get the url based upon what is in the browser
var url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
//build the image url from this
var imgurl = url + "/assets/img/generic.png";
//plug it into the jQuery selector
$("#imageid").attr("src",imgurl);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I want to set image using javascript. help me in setting the path of my image.

Comment: @sahu I just added the way for you to get the image path in JavaScript.